# Reset the "inherit"ed CSS font-style

Tags: html, css

I have the following in the main.css:

```
a, ..., em, ..., var {
    ...
    font-style: inherit;
    ...
}
```

Because of this, the `<em>` elements are not italic anymore on the site pages.

I don't know who and why put that, but I don't want to change it. However, in my particular class, say `MyClass`, I want that the  font-style element behaves like it should behave without any css rule.

Is it possible?

I tried

```
.MyClass em {
    font-style: initial;
}
```

but this didn't help...

I could put "italic", but I want that the browser itself decide how it should display this tag....

Comment: do you have a live version? `initial` should work in most browsers, however it looks like IE doesnt support it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

Comment: @Era: He's trying to cancel out the `inherit`, not seal it in.

Comment: Semi-related, a repository of browser default CSS: https://github.com/sw4/revert.css

Comment: it looks like the issue based on your provided link is that your `<em>` is having its content wrapped with multiple `<font>` tags (a single one will inherit from `em`, but a second one will inherit from `font`)

Comment: the `<em style="font-style: initial">italic text</em>` does not work either...

Comment: Please note that in modern browsers (Chrome 84; Firefox 67) you can use the `revert` keyword, which does exactly what the OP intended. `.MyClass em {font-style: revert;}`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`initial` does not mean browser default, it means CSS default, which is on a per-property basis and does not change depending on the element.

There is no way to use CSS to tell a browser to use its default styles. It should be sufficient to just set `font-style: italic` if you do not wish to remove it from the reset styles, since that's how pretty much every browser styles `em` elements.